# document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").innerHTML fails writing into input field

Tags: javascript, html, input, innerhtml

I have a little problem by writing some text into this input-field.

```
<input type="text" data-pseudo-text="true" data-selector=".attribute-orderfield1--hidden" placeholder="some text" name="attribute_orderfield1_value" id="attribute_orderfield1_value" class="input--attribute-orderfield1" data-type-aof="input">
```

I tried it before in a test without the attribute data-type-aof and it worked.

```
document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").innerHTML = "some text";
```

Is this attribute preventing writing into the field via JS?

Comment: It's .value not .innerHTML

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick here. It is in a Plugin, where i try to change the value in the input. I thought to might get around diving into the code of it, but there is a bunch of other JS in the Plugin which prevents writing/or overwrites it right after changing the value.

Thanks again for the great and quick answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are just trying to set the value, just use:

```
document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").value = "some text";
```

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML is used to add html elements to respective DOM elements. For input elements use `value` instead.

```js
document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").value = "NEW Text";
```

```html
<input type="text" data-pseudo-text="true" data-selector=".attribute-orderfield1--hidden" placeholder="some text" name="attribute_orderfield1_value" id="attribute_orderfield1_value" class="input--attribute-orderfield1" data-type-aof="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").value = "some text";
```

Try It InnerHTML not Equal to value

Answer (score 0):

With input fields you're not supposed to use innerHTML to change the text inside. Technically what you're trying to change is the [value] attribute of the input field.

Try the following JS

```
document.getElementById("attribute_orderfield1_value").value = "New Text In Input Field";
```

Comment: Didn't do the trick. :(